# Как исправить ошибку в JavaScript с if...else?

Tags: javascript, html

Первый раз пробую прогать на JS. Сделал простую страничу с 2 текстовыми полями и одной кнопкой. При нажатии на кнопку должны браться данные с полей и выводить их сумму в `alert()` Но вылезает ошибка.

Подскажите, как ее решить?

### Код

```js
function func() {
    var x = document.getElementById("text1").value;
    var y = document.getElementById("text2").value;
    var z = x + y;
    if (x == ' ') and (y == ' '){
        alert("Поля пустые");
    }
    else{
        alert("Вы ввели: " + x + " и " + y + ". А получаете: " + z);
    }
}
```

### Ошибка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот с &&

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В JS нет логического оператора and. Используйте вместо него &&.

Comment: @Lukas, ааааа, спасибо) Я просто с Python пришёл XD

Comment: @Lukas, тоже самое пишет XD

Comment: Скобки вокруг условия

Comment: if (x == '' && y == '')

Comment: Ок. Ща попробуем

Comment: Большое спасибо)

Comment: `var x = Number( document.getElementById("text1").value );` — из value всегда прилетает строка, если ожидается работа с числом, хорошо бы изначально превратить её в число. Потому что `"1" + "2" == "12"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почитайте про то как работают логические операторы в js, и используйте строгую проверку `===`

```
function func() {
        var x = document.getElementById("text1").value;
        var y = document.getElementById("text2").value;
        var z = x + y;
        if (x === '' && y === '') {
            alert("Поля пустые");
        } else {
            alert("Вы ввели: " + x + " и " + y + ". А получаете: " + z);
        }
```